In the R function rank_trace, does there exist a common threshold value to accept a rank?
In the R package rrr (document) which is used for Reduced Rank Regression, there is a function rank_trace.
It returns a plot with each rank of the regression coefficient matrix corresponding to a point.
Usually, if the point is close to the origin $(0,0)$, then we prefer that this rank is acceptable.
My question is that, for instance in $p$-value, we are usually willing to accept a hypothesis if $p>0.05$, i.e. $0.05$ is a threshold value for $p$.
Although I know this bound is not universal, I still wonder when processing data (for instance, from a trial), is there any common threshold for $\max\{x,y\}$ where $(x,y)$ is the point corresponding to some rank, to accept this rank?
It also confuses me that, in the book Modern Multivariate Statistical Techniques, where the rrr package refers to,
the author said

Assess the rank of $C$ as the smallest rank for which both coordinates from step (3) (i.e. coordinate of the point corresponding to that rank) are approximately zero.

But in the following picture on the book, the author said the smallest rank is respectively $1$ and $5$, the $x$-coordinate of both far from zero.


Additional Information: method of the function rank_trace:
Let the reduced rank regression model be
$$Y=\mu+CX+\epsilon.$$
In rank_trace plot, the coordinate of the point corresponding to $\text{rank }C=t$, is given by
$$x_t= \frac{\|\widehat{\mathbf{\Theta}} - \widehat{\mathbf{C}}^{(t)}\|}{\|\widehat{\mathbf{\Theta}}\|} ,\quad y_t=  \frac{\|\widehat{\Sigma}_{\varepsilon \varepsilon} - \widehat{\Sigma}^{(t)}_{\varepsilon \varepsilon}\|}{\|\widehat{\Sigma}_{\varepsilon \varepsilon} - \widehat{\Sigma}_{\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{Y}}\|}, $$
where the norm of a matrix is $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}$,
$\widehat{\mathbf{\Theta}}$ is the estimation of the regression coefficient matrix $C$ under full rank,
$\widehat{\Sigma}_{\varepsilon \varepsilon}$ is the estimation of $\epsilon$ under full rank,
and supscript $\cdot^{(t)}$ means estimating under the hypothesis that $C$ has rank $t$.

There is votes to close as a software question, but I vote to leave open as I see it as not primarily about software. Maybe edit to emphasize this?

Thanks for the advice. I have added the method of the rank_trace function.
